# change button onmouseover to onclick

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, mouseover

```
changeButton.className = 'change button types-popup';
const changePopup = document.createElement('div');
changeButton.appendChild(changePopup);
changeButton.onmouseover = e => {
   if (!e.target.classList.contains('types-popup')) return;
   changePopup.innerHTML = '':
   renderTypes(changePopup, type => {
       defectData.action = 'update';
       defectData.type = type.id;
       textDiv.children[0].innerText = type.description;
       closePopups();
   });
```

I completely have no understanding js. So may you help me to change this onmouseover to onclick open/close? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Comment: `changeButton.onclick` is not working for you?

Comment: if i'll just change to onclick it will close onclick too without any additionals?

Comment: You mean you want it to toggle? Did you try onclick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `changeButton.onmouseover` to `changeButton.onclick`

See [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

```
changeButton.className = 'change button types-popup';
const changePopup = document.createElement('div');
changeButton.appendChild(changePopup);
changeButton.onclick = e => {
   if (!e.target.classList.contains('types-popup')) return;
   changePopup.innerHTML = '':
   renderTypes(changePopup, type => {
       defectData.action = 'update';
       defectData.type = type.id;
       textDiv.children[0].innerText = type.description;
       closePopups();
   });
```

Comment: it will close onclick too? i can't check